# Imagen se vuelve codigo al subirla desde la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, web, imagen

tengo un problema.. a veces cuando subo imagenes desde la base de datos por phpmyadmin, la imagen mostrada se transforma en caracteres especiales tal como muestro en la imagen. Alguien sabe por que sucede eso?

[image: Ejemplo]
[image: Tabla de datos]
[image: Estructura]

```
<?php
//Declaracion de variables
$etiqueta = $_POST["etiqueta"];
$autor = $_POST["autor"];
$fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
$titulo = $_POST["titulo"];
$subtitulo = $_POST["subtitulo"];
$texto = $_POST["texto"];
$texto2 = $_POST["texto2"];
$imagenCortesia = $_POST["cortesia"];
$imagen_nombre = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
$imagen_archivo = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
$ruta = "imagenesNoticias";
$ruta = $ruta."/".$imagen_nombre;

//Crear Variables para conexion Noticias Principales
$host = "localhost";
$user = "kautivai_EditorDeNoticias";
$pw = "0927410654marvin";
$dataBase1 = "kautivai_DatosDeNoticias";

//========================= Consulta ============================//

//Consulta de campos llenos
if(isset($_POST['etiqueta']) && !empty($_POST['etiqueta']) &&
isset($_POST['autor']) && !empty($_POST['autor']) && 
isset($_POST['fecha']) && !empty($_POST['fecha']) &&
isset($_POST['titulo']) && !empty($_POST['titulo']) &&
isset($_POST['subtitulo']) && !empty($_POST['subtitulo']) &&
isset($_POST['texto']) && !empty($_POST['texto']) &&
isset($_POST['texto2']) && !empty($_POST['texto2']) &&
isset($_POST['cortesia']) && !empty($_POST['cortesia']) &&
isset($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']) && !empty($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'])){

    $conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw) or die("Problemas al conectar con base de datos 'kautivai_DatosDeNoticias'");
    mysqli_select_db($conexion, $dataBase1) or die("Problemas al conectar con base de datos 'kautivai_DatosDeNoticias'");

    move_uploaded_file($imagen_archivo, $ruta);


            mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO Noticia1(Etiqueta, Autor, Fecha, Titulo, Subtitulo, Texto, Texto2, Cortesia, RutaImagen) VALUES ('$etiqueta', '$autor', '$fecha', '$titulo', '$subtitulo', '$texto', '$texto2', '$imagenCortesia', '$ruta')");

            echo "<script>
                    alert('Los Datos han sido guardados, Base de datos actualizada!');
                    window.history.go(-1);
                </script>";


} else {
    echo "Problemas al insertar los Datos en la base de datos 'kautivai_DatosDeNoticias'";
}

mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

Comment: Hola, las imagenes no pueden ser subidas a una base de datos, se suben a una carpeta en el servidor y en la base de datos se guarda es la RUTA de la imagen, no la imagen como tal.

Comment: Justamente eso es lo q he hecho, y me funciona cuando subo la imagen desde mi pagina de administracion, pero cuando la subo desde phpmyadmin sucede eso... La imagen no esta subida en la tabla, solo esta guardada la ruta

Comment: Actualiza tu respuesta donde muestres el codigo que estas usando para subir la imagen creo que te falta un parametro.

Comment: actualizado....

Comment: Ya vi el error y realice mi respectiva respuesta, si te funciona no olvides calificar como respuesta desde el check (✔) que se encuentra al lado izquierdo de la respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisando tu código y tabla el error esta en el tipo de dato que esta utilizando la columna RutaImagen de tu tabla:

El tipo de dato `BLOB` es para binarios, `LONGBLOB` es para bastantes caracteres binarios.

Utiliza la siguiente Query para cambiarlo, o desde phpmyadmin.

```
ALTER TABLE nombre_tabla MODIFY RutaImagen varchar(255) NOT NULL;
```

Utilice varchar pero tu puedes usar longtext si quieres, eso depende de tu necesidad.